# Show that $\vec F=\left(\frac{y + z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{x + z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{y + x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$ is irrotational but not conservative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Show that $$\vec F=\left(\frac{y + z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{x + z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{y + x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$$ in $\mathbb R^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$ is irrotational but not conservative.

I can show that $\vec F$ is irrotational by proving $curl\,\vec F=0$.

Please help me to show that $\vec F$  is not conservative.

The line integral for $C:\vec r=(acos t, a sint, 0)$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, circle centered at origin is
$$\int F.dr=\int_0^{2\pi}cos\, 2t\,dt=0$$

We have to consider a closed curve such that $\int F.dr\neq 0$, then we are done!!!

But how to show this?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Since $H_1(\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}) \cong H_1(S^2)$ is trivial, all irrotational vector fields on $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$ are conservative.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you for your comment. I saw it in a note. I understand that it is wrong. Is it possible for you to provide me an example of $F: R^3\to R^3$ such that F is irrotational but not conservative?

Comment: @user1932348 No, for the same reason: $H_1(\Bbb R^3)$ is also trivial. But $\left(-\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}, 0\right)$ is irrotational but not conservative. (This example really just tacks an extra coordinate onto the so-called "vortex vector field" on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\vec{F}$ is not irrotational:
\begin{align}
\nabla\times\vec{F}=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_yF_z-\partial_zF_y\\\partial_zF_x-\partial_xF_z\\\partial_xF_y-\partial_yF_x \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\partial_yF_z-\partial_zF_y&=\frac{\cancel{x^2+y^2+z^2}-(y+x)2y-\cancel{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}+(x+z)2z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}\\
&=2\frac{-y^2-xy+xz+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
\partial_zF_x-\partial_xF_z&=2\frac{-z^2-yz+xy+x^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
\partial_xF_y-\partial_yF_x&=2\frac{-x^2-xz+yz+y^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}\,.
\end{align}

To address the comment that you are searching for a field in $\mathbb R^3$ that is irrotational but not conservative.

- As Travis Willse pointed out: when the only singularities are isolated points every irrotational field in $\mathbb R^3$ is conservative.
- What you have to look for is a field that has a singularity on a line such that it is not possible to contract a loop around that line to a single point. Take for example the $z$-axis. The most popular irrotational field that is not conservative is
  $$
  \vec{F}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am sorry that I am only check the line integral and not the curl. I am searching for an example of F:R3→R3
 such that F is irrotational but not conservative

Comment: Ok, is it possible to find F including x, y and z?

Comment: Anything else I could do for you Sir?  Try a few modifications and calculate the curl this time. You could add to a that $F$ two copies of  it where the singularity is on the $x$-axis and on the $y$-axis

Comment: What you said is true. I am trying after your first post. Not finding till now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: A fairly simple example that includes $z$ is $$\vec{F}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\f(z)\end{pmatrix}\,$$

Comment: excellent .......